# How to Customize Mobile View or Integrate Jquery Mobile into an already made SharePoint 2010 public facing site?

Tags: 2010, jquery, mobile

I'm very new to SharePoint Development and need some instruction or direction on how to customize the mobile view or use Jquery mobile on a SharePoint 2010 public facing site.

I have been tasked with making a few sites touchscreen friendly as hover's don't work on touch devices. I have been told the Mobile View and/or Jquery Mobile can do this on already completed sites.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the MSDN documentation on creating mobile views: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861936.aspx

Here is a blog post that goes through the process of adding JQuery Mobile to a SharePoint 2010 site:

http://devspoint.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/jquery-mobile-and-sharepoint/

Comment: Thanks for the links is there a way for the second one to work on a public facing site and not use the Feed API? I'm trying to get everything saved locally with out having to access outside services.

Comment: You only need to use the Feeds API to reference external servers, if the news feeds are from your sharepoint server you can use RSS